# Content does not show after publishing

Tags: publishing

I have a site running Sitecore 8.0 (Win Forms) with some problems publishing. What steps should be taken to troubleshoot this?

The site has problems both on a local development environment and in the Live scaled environment.

Symptoms include:

- Content does not show up unless IIS is recycled.
- Content disappears that used to show. Primarily (maybe only?) images are affected.
- Some content shows up after several days.
- Some content does not show up at all no matter what steps are taken.

Steps already taken:

- Checking that all related content is published such as templates, sublayouts, placeholder settings. Verifying that these exist in the web database.
- Republishing using Republish everything.
- Clearing Sitecore caches
- Reindexing

In the case of content that shows up after resetting IIS, I suspect that there is some ASP.Net caching going on that I have not yet been able to find. How could that be confirmed or how could Sitecore be ruled out? What else should be suspected?

Comment: Have you checked by clearing your caches from `/siteore/admin/cache.aspx` instead of doing an IIS reset? Are you running multi-site and have you set your `publish:end:*` handlers to include all sites?

Comment: I did clear the Sitecore caches from `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`. There is only one site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of steps to take here:

1. as JammyKam mentioned check /siteore/admin/cache.aspx to see what is being stored in the cache
2. also look at /sitecore/admin/stats.aspx also to see what components are cached
3. check your cache settings, i.e do you have Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits set to true or specific cache settings for templates and also your pre-fetch cache settings :https://reasoncodeexample.com/2013/03/20/sitecore-cache-settings-for-slackers/
4. check you have event queues enabled (EnableEventQueues) : http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/07/sitecore-event-queue-scalability-king.html
5. check Your publish:end and publish:end:remote handlers include the Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer class, with all sites included: https://rcchopra.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/sitecore-publishing-cache/
6. Take a look at the pages using the debug tool: http://practicaltinkering.essertown.com/2015/01/troubleshooting-sitecore-performance.html
7. Look at the cache settings on your renderings on sitecore and on the layout details of pages and see what the 'vary by' settings are set to.
8. Take a look at your page layout code and component/controller code and see if you have output caching enabled or custom caches.

This should be a good start to finding out what the issue is.

Comment: This client took their development in house, so I was not able to see this to its resolution. This list looks pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Also, might check to see if you have enabled any browser cache settings: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: Rob, can you add some detail? Maybe walk us through what the link is describing?

Comment: Do not provide link-only answers, from the "How to Answer" guide: Provide context for links
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.