# Content update to Sitecore application is not going live immediately

Tags: publishing, content-delivery

Our Sitecore application has a separate content editorial and content delivery sites. We publish content and it was working fine till recent days. Recently from a week or two, the content is not immediately getting onto live site.

We thought it may be a cache issue and did check the following steps suggested in this answers [Content does not show after publishing,](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/649/content-does-not-show-after-publishing) but all went in vain. The content is showing up on databases web and master but its not on live site. Some times we have to republish and sometimes we have to reset the app pool for the content to be on live site. And some other times the content will be published on its own after an hour or two. Please help.

Comment: While trying to publish do you see any publishing queue and did you check logs for any errors?

Comment: When you publish an item, check the eventqueue stats from the admin page. All events will get triggered only when those event counts are sync

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the HTML cache that does not get cleared.
If you have created multiple  definitions, you need to make sure that the delivery site clears the HTML cache.
the publish:end:remote event has a HTMLCacheClearer defined with a list of sites to clear cache for.
Remember to add your custom sites to this list

```
<event name="publish:end:remote" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config">
<handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
<sites hint="list">
<site>website</site>
<site>*Add your site(s) here*</site>
</sites>
</handler>
```